# Hard and challenging homework problem about conditional probabilities.

Tags: probability

I've been thinking a lot on this exercise(about 2 weeks without asking help) and I can't solve it, so I would like you to help me. It is important to me.

> A fishing vessel has disappeared and it is presumed that its disappearance is due to one of three possible causes:

$C_1$ - sank when he experimented a sophisticated fishing system for which he was not minimally equipped;

$C_2$ - was hijacked for carrying a shipment of nuclear material;

$C_3$ - was destroyed by a thunderstorm.

> Three search and rescue brigades, $B_1$, $B_2$ and $B_3$ were sent with the mission to do the search of the boat, each investigating one of the causes (i.e. $B_i$ brigade investigates the cause $C_i$).

Suppose that:

**1)** the three causes of disappearance are equally probable;

**2)** the probability of brigade $B_i$ to be successful when in fact the boat disappeared due to the cause $C_i$ is **i: (1 = 0.1, 2 = 0.7, 3 = 0.8)**.

> Knowing that the investigation of brigade $B_2$ proved to be fruitless, calculate the probability:

**A)** The boat has been hijacked.

**B)** The boat has been destroyed by a storm.

So, first we want $P(C_2|B_2)$, and then we want $P(C_3|B_2)$ .. This exercise is particularly hard to me to understand, because since Brigade 1 only studies the cause $C_1$, how can $P(B_1|C_2)$ be different of zero? or $P(B_1|C_3)$, etc etc.

Comment: There are three reasons $B_2$ might have failed:  if $C_1$ or $C_3$ are the cause then $B_2$ fails with probability $1$.  If $C_2$ is the cause the $B_2$ fails with probability $.3$.  Use Bayes Theorem to re-estimate the probability that $C_2$ is the cause...the answer you want is just $1$ minus that.

Comment: $P(B_1\mid C_2)$ is zero.

Comment: Please _never_ write anything like "$1=0.1$" in any mathematical writing (or anywhere else if you can avoid it). It makes no sense. If you want to show us formulas to define the probabilities, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Presumably, by "equally provable," you mean "equally probable?" Those are slightly different things in this case...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so what is the probability of P(B1) ? Is it P(B1)=0.1*(1/3) ?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes.

Comment: Assuming that "equally provable" meant $P(C_1)=P(C_2)=P(C_3)$, yes, $P(B_1)=0.1\cdot \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @lulu How could I realize it was needed Bayes formula?

Comment: The problem is a bit nonsensical to begin with, which may be part of the difficulty. We don't ask search-and-rescue teams to investigate causes of an accident, only to find the boat or the survivors. So the "cause" could at most suggest the most likely places to look. There is no mathematical reason why there should be zero probability that a storm could leave the boat in the same place team $B_2$ looks for a hijacked boat. Hence we have to guess the intentions of the problem setter, which seem to be that $P(B_i\mid C_j)=0$ when $i\neq j.$

Comment: "How could I realize it was needed Bayes formula?" You knew conditional probabilities were involved when you wrote the title of the question. _Always_ consider Bayes' theorem when conditional probabilities are involved and the answer isn't instantly obvious.

Comment: This is exactly what Bayes Theorem is for...knowing that $B_2$ failed is evidence (though not proof) that $C_2$ was not the cause.  That evidence allows us to recalibrate our estimate of the probabilities.

Comment: @lulu look at this image, and tell me if these are equivalent. Since B1 can be only sucessful when the cause is C1, the probability of P(B1∩C1)=0,1*(1/3). Could I do the same thing to P(B2∩C1) if I knew P(B2|C1) ?

[IMG]http://i66.tinypic.com/2drk04.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: @lulu according to your first answer, we can't say that those tree diagrams are equivalent, right? That was the hardest part to me to understand. the fact B1 succeeds since the cause was C1 doesnt mean the remaining probability (0.9) is the probability of B2 or B3 succeeds. right?

Comment: That link doesn't open for me.  But, honestly, the calculation is simple.  The revised estimate for the probability of $C_2$ is $p^*_2=\frac {\frac 13\times .3}{\frac 13\times .3+\frac 23\times 1}=\frac 17$

Comment: Sorry, added wrong.  That expression is $\frac 3{23}$. not $\frac 17$.

Comment: @lulu yes, that's right. Thank you. And thanks for the advice about Bayes's formula application. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider running this experiment 30 times with 10 times each for $C_1,C_2,C_3$. Of those, $B_2$ only occurs 0.7 of the times when $C_2$ is true -that is, $7$ times.

That leaves $23$ times for the cases when $B_2$ is not true.

Of those, ten still have $C_1$ true, and ten have $C_3$ true.

Comment: look at this image, and tell me if these are equivalent. Since B1 can be only sucessful when the cause is C1, the probability of P(B1∩C1)=0,1*(1/3). Could I do the same thing to P(B2∩C1) if I knew P(B2|C1) ?

[IMG]http://i66.tinypic.com/2drk04.jpg[/IMG]